# Azure Data Factory - Update environment variable in continues integration pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I have recently started with ARM and Azure Data Factory, and now I have faced a problem when I try to deploy ADF into other environments. Because the source connection string are different in each environment and I can not keep the static value in adf.content.parameters.json file.
So I have created three YML files for each environment as Dev.yml, Test.yml, and Prod.yml. I have three files

1. adf.content.json
2. adf.content.parameters.json
3. Dev.yml, test.yml and prod.yml

In the file, adf.content.json, I have a connection string as my source. This value is changing in each environment. Here is the adf.content.parameters.json

```
"parameters": {
"source_connectionString": {
  "type": "secureString",
  "metadata": "Secure string for 'connectionString' of 'source-db'"
},
```

and I removed this parameter from adf.content.parameters.json but instead, I have added that to Dev.yml file which looks like this one (Test.yml and prod.yml are the same just different values)

```
variables:
 - name:  source-connectionstring
   value: <some value>
```

I have a ci-build.yml and ci-deploy.yml files which will be used for the CI pipeline. In the ci-build.yml file, I use the same name in the adf.content.json

```
variables:
 SourceConnectionString: $(source_connectionString:?You need to set the source_connectionString environment variable)


- stage: DevDeploy
  displayName: Deploy to development (D)
  variables:
   - template: ../.../.../dev.yml
   - group: ...
  dependsOn: Build
 jobs: 
   - template: cd_deploy.yml
    parameters:
      environment: dev
      azureServiceConnection: '...'
      containerRegistryDomain: ...
      apiResourceGroup: '...' 
      webAppName: '...
      azureSubscriptionName: ...
      apimResourceGroup: ...
      apimName:  ...
```

And in my ci-deply.yml file looks like this

```
task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
          displayName: "Deploy Azure Data Factory Content"
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '...'
            action: '...'
            resourceGroupName: '...'
            location: '...'
            templateLocation: '...'
            csmFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/.../arm/adf.content.json'
            csmParametersFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/../arm/adf.content.parameters.json'
            overrideParameters: ' -source_connectionString$(SourceConnectionString) 
            deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

But I get an error " did not find expected key" on `overrideParameters: ' -source_connectionString$(SourceConnectionString)`

I do not know if this is the right approach for this? and if anyone can get why I can not get the key?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by wrong syntax.

In `ci-deply.yml`, the script `overrideParameters: ' -source_connectionString$(SourceConnectionString)` loses a `'`.

So your task in `ci-deply.yml` should look like this:

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: "Deploy Azure Data Factory Content"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '...'
    action: '...'
    resourceGroupName: '...'
    location: '...'
    templateLocation: '...'
    csmFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/.../arm/adf.content.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/../arm/adf.content.parameters.json'
    overrideParameters: ' -source_connectionString$(SourceConnectionString) '
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Comment: oh, it seems I missed it when I copied it here. but thanks for your answer

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr The error message tells that the syntax is incorrect. Maybe you used TAB instead of space, or something else. In addition, this error messgae often confuses the location of the error, so it's best to check the entire file. You can try replacing your code with mine to see if it still goes wrong. If it still fails, please check all the spaces and replace all '' by "" in the entire file. If there is any update, please let me know.